# Please prove/disprove $y=f(x),x=f(y)\Leftrightarrow x=f(f(x))$

Tags: functions, propositional-calculus

A Japanese math educator once said, "You should not use equivalence symbols in college entrance exams [omitted] because students will misuse them like $y=f(x),x=f(y)\Leftrightarrow x=f(f(x))$. There is no way that two expressions can be equivalent to one expression."
This argument is considered wrong (because many professors have refuted it), but I was curious about the proposition he illustrated and tried to prove/disprove it, but I couldn't come to a conclusion that convinced myself, so I'll ask the question here.
Therefore please prove/disprove the following propositions.

$y=f(x),x=f(y)\Leftrightarrow x=f(f(x))$ (Original)

$\forall x,\exists y;{x=f(y)}\wedge {y=f(x)} \Leftrightarrow \forall x;x=f(f(x))$

I tried to quantify it appropriately, but I wasn't sure from his original text what the correct way to define the domain of definition was, so I left it as is.

Comment: You need to use parentheses to disambiguate $\forall x,\exists y;x=f(y)\wedge y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without quantifiers, the potential equivalence has to be read as
$$
\forall x\,\forall y\colon \big[(y=f(x) \wedge x=f(y)) \Longleftrightarrow x=f(f(x)) \big],
$$
where we still need to specify what $f$ is and where $x$ and $y$ are taken from.

Let's take $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ and consider the case where $x=1$ and $y=2$. The potential equivalence then states that
$$
(2=1\wedge 1=2)\Longleftrightarrow 1=1.
$$
Note that the left proposition is false while the right proposition is true. Hence, the equivalence is false for this case of $f$, $x$ and $y$. Thus, it is false in general.

Comment: Is there a clear proof/counterexample for the version with the quantifier?

Comment: @yuuki76 The one with "$\forall x\,\exists y$" is true: For $\Rightarrow$ just substitute $y=f(x)$ into $x=f(y)$. For $\Leftarrow$ just set $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.